# Image Links are not clickable, but are on the hosting providers end

Tags: html, wordpress

so i have an issue on my site https://audiencepleasers.com/  where the Image Links along with some other links dont work. For instance, i should be able to click on the "Carnival Theme Party" Image or text and it should bring me to my page on carnival themed parties. The "more" link at the bottom of my home page also isn't clickable.

```
<!-- [if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!-- [if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!-- [if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->

Carnival, Casino Night, and Corporate Party Planning New Jersey | AudiencePleasers.com
<!-- [if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- FlexSlider -->

&nbsp;

<script defer src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function(){

      SyntaxHighlighter.all();

    });

    jQuery(window).load(function(){

      jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({

        animation: "slide",

        start: function(slider){

          jQuery('body').removeClass('loading');

        }

      });

    });

  </script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-69879002-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<!-- All in One SEO Pack 2.3.10.1 by Michael Torbert of Semper Fi Web Design[313,379] -->

&nbsp;

<!-- /all in one seo pack -->
<script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/audiencepleasers.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.6.1"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c,d,e,f,g,h=b.createElement("canvas"),i=h.getContext&&h.getContext("2d"),j=String.fromCharCode;if(!i||!i.fillText)return!1;switch(i.textBaseline="top",i.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return i.fillText(j(55356,56806,55356,56826),0,0),!(h.toDataURL().length<3e3)&&(i.clearRect(0,0,h.width,h.height),i.fillText(j(55356,57331,65039,8205,55356,57096),0,0),c=h.toDataURL(),i.clearRect(0,0,h.width,h.height),i.fillText(j(55356,57331,55356,57096),0,0),d=h.toDataURL(),c!==d);case"diversity":return i.fillText(j(55356,57221),0,0),e=i.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,f=e[0]+","+e[1]+","+e[2]+","+e[3],i.fillText(j(55356,57221,55356,57343),0,0),e=i.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,g=e[0]+","+e[1]+","+e[2]+","+e[3],f!==g;case"simple":return i.fillText(j(55357,56835),0,0),0!==i.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0];case"unicode8":return i.fillText(j(55356,57135),0,0),0!==i.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0];case"unicode9":return i.fillText(j(55358,56631),0,0),0!==i.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0]}return!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g,h,i;for(i=Array("simple","flag","unicode8","diversity","unicode9"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},h=0;h<i.length;h++)c.supports[i[h]]=d(i[h]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[i[h]],"flag"!==i[h]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[i[h]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>

<style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,<br />img.emoji {<br />   display: inline !important;<br />   border: none !important;<br />  box-shadow: none !important;<br />  height: 1em !important;<br />   width: 1em !important;<br />    margin: 0 .07em !important;<br />   vertical-align: -0.1em !important;<br />    background: none !important;<br />  padding: 0 !important;<br />}<br /></style>

<!-- [if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='twentytwelve-ie-css' href='http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/css/ie.css?ver=20121010' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-responsive-menu/js/jquery.transit.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-responsive-menu/js/jquery.sidr.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */ var wprmenu = {"zooming":"yes","from_width":"768","swipe":"no"}; /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-responsive-menu/js/wprmenu.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/plugins/testimonial-rotator/js/jquery.cycletwo.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/plugins/testimonial-rotator/js/jquery.cycletwo.addons.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>

<style id="wprmenu_css" type="text/css" >
            /* apply appearance settings */<br />           #wprmenu_bar {<br />                background: #0D0D0D;<br />          }<br />         #wprmenu_bar .menu_title, #wprmenu_bar .wprmenu_icon_menu {<br />               color: #F2F2F2;<br />           }<br />         #wprmenu_menu {<br />               background: #2E2E2E!important;<br />            }<br />         #wprmenu_menu.wprmenu_levels ul li {<br />              border-bottom:1px solid #131212;<br />              border-top:1px solid #0D0D0D;<br />         }<br />         #wprmenu_menu ul li a {<br />               color: #CFCFCF;<br />           }<br />         #wprmenu_menu ul li a:hover {<br />             color: #606060;<br />           }<br />         #wprmenu_menu.wprmenu_levels a.wprmenu_parent_item {<br />              border-left:1px solid #0D0D0D;<br />            }<br />         #wprmenu_menu .wprmenu_icon_par {<br />             color: #CFCFCF;<br />           }<br />         #wprmenu_menu .wprmenu_icon_par:hover {<br />               color: #606060;<br />           }<br />         #wprmenu_menu.wprmenu_levels ul li ul {<br />               border-top:1px solid #131212;<br />         }<br />         #wprmenu_bar .wprmenu_icon span {<br />             background: #FFFFFF;<br />          }</p>
<p>         #wprmenu_menu.left {<br />              width:80%;<br />                left: -80%;<br />               right: auto;<br />          }<br />         #wprmenu_menu.right {<br />             width:80%;<br />                right: -80%;<br />              left: auto;<br />           }</p>
<p>                     /* show the bar and hide othere navigation elements */<br />            @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {<br />               html { padding-top: 42px!important; }<br />             #wprmenu_bar { display: block!important; }<br />                div#wpadminbar { position: fixed; }<br />               .main_nav { display:none!important; }           }<br />     </style> <style type='text/css'>img#wpstats{display:none}</style>

<!-- Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->

<!-- BEGIN GADWP v4.9.3.2 Universal Tracking - https://deconf.com/google-analytics-dashboard-wordpress/ -->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-69144232-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<!-- END GADWP Universal Tracking -->



&nbsp;

&nbsp;
<div id="page" class="hfeed site"><header class="header">
<div class="up_header"></div>
<div class="logo"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/"><img class="alignnone" src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/logo2.png" alt="audience pleasers" width="418" height="96" /></a></div>
<div class="nav_main">
<div class="call">Call 1 (888) AUD-PLEASE 1 (888) 283-7532</div>
<div class="fb_tiwtt"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/AudiencePleasersEntertainment" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/image/fb.png" /></a><a href="https://twitter.com/audpleas" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <img src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/image/tiwitter.png" /></a></div>
</div>
<nav class="nav">
<div class="main_nav">
<div class="menu-header-container">
<ul id="menu-header" class="nav-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-21"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/entertainers/">Entertainment</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/themesevents/">Themes</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/amusements/">Amusements</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/our-clients/">Our Clients</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-101"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/category/news-events/">News &amp; Events</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/fundraising/">Fundraising</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1888" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1888"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/professional-links/">Professional Links</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav></header><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/fancybox/video.js"></script>`

<section class="section">
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="welcome">
<h1>Welcome to AUDIENCE PLEASERS</h1>
</div>
<div class="main_center">
<div class="casinos_two">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/casino-night-themed-party/"><img class="attachment-211x195 wp-post-image alignnone" src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/postcard-casino.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 211px) 100vw, 211px" srcset="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/postcard-casino.jpg 525w, http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/postcard-casino-300x214.jpg 300w" alt="audience pleasers" width="211" height="151" /></a>
<a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/casino-night-themed-party/">Casino Night Themed Party</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/carnival-themed-party/ "><img class="attachment-211x195 wp-post-image alignnone" src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/postcard-carnival.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 211px) 100vw, 211px" srcset="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/postcard-carnival.jpg 525w, http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/postcard-carnival-300x214.jpg 300w" alt="audience pleasers" width="211" height="151" /></a>
<a class="home_btn" href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/carnival-themed-party/">Carnival Themed Party</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/corporate-team-building/ "><img class="attachment-211x195 wp-post-image alignnone" src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Postcard-Corporate-Team-Building.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 211px) 100vw, 211px" srcset="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Postcard-Corporate-Team-Building.jpg 525w, http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Postcard-Corporate-Team-Building-300x214.jpg 300w" alt="audience pleasers" width="211" height="151" /></a>
<a class="home_btn" href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/corporate-team-building/">Corporate Team Building</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/murder-mystery-party-2/ "><img class="attachment-211x195 wp-post-image alignnone" src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Murder-Mystery-Party.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 211px) 100vw, 211px" srcset="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Murder-Mystery-Party.jpg 525w, http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Murder-Mystery-Party-300x214.jpg 300w" alt="audience pleasers" width="211" height="151" /></a>
<a class="home_btn" href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/murder-mystery-party-2/">Murder Mystery Party</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/magic-themed-party/ "><img class="attachment-211x195 wp-post-image alignnone" src="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/original-pc.png" sizes="(max-width: 211px) 100vw, 211px" srcset="http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/original-pc.png 628w, http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/original-pc-300x211.png 300w, http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/original-pc-250x176.png 250w, http://audiencepleasers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/original-pc-624x439.png 624w" alt="audience pleasers" width="211" height="149" /></a>
<a href="http://audiencepleasers.com/all-theme/magic-themed-party/">Magic Themed Party</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li id="text-4" class="widget widget_text">
<div class="textwidget">
<h1>Celebrating over 4 decades of fine entertainment!</h1>
Audience Pleasers is one of the leading producers of events and entertainment-related projects for corporations, associations, charitable organizations and private individuals for over 4 decades.Our entertainment services include planning, negotiating and executing special events, from 20 to 5000 people, world-wide.

We provide full service event production agency, Audience Pleasers also offers its services on a subcontracting basis to a wide variety of marketing, communication &amp; public relations firms, and meeting &amp; event producers.

Event Planners, Caterers, Entertainment Agencies, Rental Companies, and other Event Specialists often utilize Audience Pleasers’s large inventory of equipment, as well as book performers and shows through Audience Pleasers. If you are an Event Professional and would like to gain access to our online pricing, please contact us to be considered.
```

Comment: All the links in question work for me using Chrome 65.0.3325.181

Comment: thanks for responding, ive tried other networks and browsers but i am still unable to view them

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? It would be greatly appreciated